# Не переходит к выполнению функци JS

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование

Есть функция проверки введенных данных в `Input`, если поле осталось пустым, добавить к нему класс `input-error`. Смотрел скрипт через отладку, после строки `form.addEventListener('submit', formSend);` прекращает работу скрипта.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const form = document.getElementById('form')
  form.addEventListener('submit', formSend);

  async function formSend(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let error = formValidate(form);
  }

  function formValidate(form) {
    let error = 0;
    let formReq = documen.querySelectorAll('.req');

    for (let index = 0; index < formReq.length; index++) {
      const input = formReq[index];
      formRemoveEror(input);

      if (input.classList.contains('email')) {
        if (emailTest(input)) {
          formAddEror(input);
          error++;
        }
      } else {
        if (input.value === '') {
          formAddEror(input);
          error++;
        }
      }

    }
  }

  function formAddEror(input) {
    input.parentElement.classList.add('input-error');
    input.classList.add('input-error')
  }

  function formRemoveEror(input) {
    input.parentElement.classList.remove('input-error');
    input.classList.remove('input-error')
  }
  //Проверка Email
  function emailTest(input) {
    return !/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,8})+$/.test(input.value);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае у Вас опечатка `documen.querySelectorAll('.req');` но я хочу предложить другой вариант проверки возможно он покажется интересным, хотя бы потому что он интерактивен.

```js
// добавляет класс ошибки только при потере фокуса
document.querySelector('input[type=url]')
  .addEventListener('blur', e => (e.target.nextSibling.classList.add('err')))

document.querySelector('input[type=email]')
  .addEventListener('blur', e => (e.target.nextSibling.classList.add('err')))

// добавляет все класы ошибок при клике на сабмит()
document.querySelector('input[type=submit]')
  .addEventListener('click', () => {
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input + span')).forEach(e => {
      e.classList.add('err')
    })
})
```

```css
/* изначально прозрачный цвет ошибки*/
input + span {
 color: transparent;
} 
/* когда ошибки нет или она исправлена */
input + span.err {
  display: block;
  color: transparent;
}
/* когда ошибка есть */
input:invalid + span.err {
  display: block;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <p>Адрес электронной почты</p>
  <p><input type="email" required><span>не правильная почта</span></p>
  <p>Адрес сайта</p>
  <p><input type="url" required><span>не правильный адрес сайта</span></p>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Отправить" /></p>
</form>
```

в дополнение к этому обратите внимание на аттибут инпута [pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern)